# Multiple exits decisions in activity-diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have one dialog where user can perform four activities

"Add product"
"delete product"
"update product"
"CANCEL"

can i make one input "product management" and put the four activies in the output of the decision block in the diagram ?

this is my example
  [image: this is my exemple]

Comment: Output from where? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would suggest you add a diagram depicting what you're considering pointing where exactly the problem lies. It'll be much easier to understand your question then.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is correct , but you have to define conditions for all outgoing flows.